# How to deploy web service on two different system within a LAN?

Tags: java, web-services, http, netbeans, fedora

I have created a web service using Netbeans in Fedora which is working fine in local host. But I want to deploy client on different computer and server on different computer.

I could also connect two Fedora systems using a LAN cable(SSH), but could not access the web service.

What is the procedure to deploy it?  Does a webDav-http service connection be established?  If so how to do that?

Comment: seems like you need your webservice to listen on something other than localhost, but I don't know beans about netbeans so can't help with the details of that

Comment: yes. forget netbeans.. i'm deploying it on Glassfish 3.1 server which listens to localhost:8080.  How to change the listening address to my ip address so that other system can listen?

Comment: have you opened the ports in the firewall to access the webservice? I'm assuming you can ssh from one box to the other, but you cannot access the webservice.

Comment: can you tell it to listen to 0.0.0.0 instead?

Comment: no. I am a newbie. How to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy your project in a different machine, compile it, and the copy the war file to the application server you desire. I use Tomcat, just need to copy the war to the webapp folder, you should have something like in glassfish.

About the clients:
What are you using to generate the client? I assume metro, since is the default in netbeans.
Create a new java project;
Add new, Web Service Client;
Create it from the url: something like http://example.com.someService?wsdl.
Changing the ip you change the machine that this client will communicate to.

Comment: Thank you,I have already done with the same procedure and it is working fine. Actually there was problem with proxy while parsing wsdl from client side to remote(server) side so inorder to eradicate you need just check the radio button "No Proxy" while creating new web service client ['This setting works for Static IP address'].